# glTexImage2D() parameters and generating framebuffers

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, glteximage2d

According to the opengl's reference page, glTexImage2D's structure looks like this:

```
void glTexImage2D(  GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLint border,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    const GLvoid * data);
```

As far as I know, the last 3 parameters are how the function should interpret the image data given by `const GLvoid * data`

Meanwhile, I was studying the topic of framebuffers. And in the section called 'Floating point framebuffers' of this link https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/HDR, the writer creates a framebuffer's color attachment like this

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

My question is, why did he give GL_FLOAT as the parameter for `GLenum type`? If `const GLvoid * data` is `NULL` anyway, is there a need to use GL_FLOAT? I first thought it's something related to `GL_RGBA16F`, but 16 bits is 2 bytes and floats are 4 bytes, so I guess it's not related at all.

Furthermore, before this tutorial, the writer used to make color attachments like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

In this case, why did he use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the `GLenum type` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the last parameter is NULL or not (assuming PBOs aren't employed), the `format` and the `type` parameters must always be *legal values* relative to the `internalformat` parameter.

That being said, it is not strictly necessary that the [pixel transfer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) `format` and `type` parameters exactly match the `internalformat`. But they do have to be *compatible* with it, in accord with the rules on [pixel transfer compatibility](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Format_conversion). In the specific cases you cite, the `format` and `type` values are all compatbile with either of the `internalforamt`s used. So you could in theory do this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

That being said, you *shouldn't*, for two reasons:

1. You shouldn't write code that you wouldn't want executed for real. Having an implementation manually convert from unsigned normalized bytes into 16-bit floats kills performance. Even if it's not actually going to do that conversion because the pointer is NULL, you still would never want it to actually happen. So write the code that makes sense.
2. You have to remember all of the rules of pixel transfer compatibility. Because if you get them *wrong*, if you ask for an illegal conversion, you get an OpenGL error and thus broken code. If you're not used to always think about what your `format` and `type` parameters are, it's really easy to switch to integer textures and get an immediate error because you didn't use one of the `_INTEGER` formats. Whereas if you're always thinking about the pixel transfer parameters that represent the `internalformat` you're actually using, you'll never encounter that error.

Comment: For completeness, IMHO it's worth mentioning that: **a)** constraints for `internalformat`, `format` and `type` are listed on ref pages: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml (Errors, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error specifically), and **b)** in OpenGL ES, those constraints are more strict (potential source of incompatibilities)